# Addressverify API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to use AddressVerify API. I am using their API calls such as SetExpressCheckout etc.

However when I try to make this API call it is giving me You do not have permission to make this API Call. I am using PayPal SDK for .NET and passing these values.

```
        AddressVerifyRequestType request = new AddressVerifyRequestType();
        request.Email = "emailaddress"
        request.Street = BillingInfo.Address;
        request.Zip = BillingInfo.StateCode;
```

Thanks and looking forward for a positive reply.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that is not enabled by default on your account.  If this is for a sandbox account, I can enable this on your test account if you provide the email address to the test sandbox seller account.  If this is for a live account, you will need to contact PayPal Merchant Services and request this to be enabled.